# lessphp fatal error: load error: failed to find error after migrating wordpress website to new server

Tags: php, wordpress, less, webserver, cherrypy

We are seeing the following error after migrating a WordPress site from one server to another.

```
lessphp fatal error: load error:
  failed to find /hermes/bosnaweb18a/b2978/ipw.m3federalcom/public_html/m3federal/wp-content/themes/theme44107/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less
lessphp fatal error: load error:
  failed to find /hermes/bosnaweb18a/b2978/ipw.m3federalcom/public_html/m3federal/wp-content/themes/theme44107/style.less
```

The domain in question is on a parked testing domain (cerwebtest.net) and you will see the error at the top after clicking on any page other than the homepage. We have updated all plugins / WordPress to latest versions from within the WordPress admin portal. I have verified that the files in the error do exist. I have tried (according to [this resource](http://smallmouthmediagroup.com/moving-wordpress-site-cherry-framework-tip-lessphp-errors/)) removing the bootstrap.less.cache and style.less.cache files to try to force it to look at the `.less` files for generating the site. It only fixed the error on the main page but not any sub pages. The site appears to be loading correctly even with the something calling those files but not finding / using them. Any ideas as to what needs to be done to correct the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we used  https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/  to find and replace incorrect database path links. they needed to be updated from /hermes/bosnaweb18a/b2978/ipw.m3federalcom/ to our current linux servers file paths. we then updated the permalinks in wp-admin. we also deleted the .cache files under wp-content to remove stored site caching. after all that, site started functioning properly.

Answer (score 23):

I just had that same error. I got rid of it by deleting the .cache files in the folders of the named files in the error message.

Delete
/wp-content/themes/theme44107/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less.cache
/wp-content/themes/theme44107/style.less.cache

After that the error message went away and the site worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just had same issue, my solution was to open the style.less cache files in text editor and check the url for the style.less file. Quick change now working